# Add the name of the file to the end of the file

Tags: bash, shell

I have 365 text files which are named after days in 2018 (Files are named 2018-01-01, 2018-01-02 etc...) and contain text. I want to add "End of the day X" Where X is the name of the file to the end of each of these files. They are all in the same directory.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
for i in *; echo "last line of i" >> i"
```

When I attempt this I get an error of...

Comment: You don't show any effort. What was your attempt?

Comment: What is a _file with dates_?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not working? Are you getting an error? Are the lines appended but they're wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With `>>` you can append content to a file. For example, this appends the string `text` to a file called `file`:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "text" >> "file"
```

That said, you could iterate over some files, say, `*.txt` and append their names to said files:

```sh
for f in *.txt; do printf '%s\n' "$f" >> "$f"; done
```